# Overloaded Constructors all display instead of just the targeted constructor

Tags: c++, oop, reference, constructor, constructor-overloading

Why doesn't the Print() function update properly after Add() function is used by object in main?

```
int main()
{
   Rational myRational(3,5);
   myRational.Print(); //Displays 3/5 as expected
   myRational.Add(2);
   myRational.Print(); //Displays 3/5 instead of 13/5
   return 0;
}

//from Rational.cpp

//Overloaded constructors
Rational::Rational() :
    num(0),
    denom(1)
{
}
Rational::Rational(int n) :
    num(n),
    denom(1)
{
}

Rational::Rational(int n, int d) :
    num(n),
    denom(d)
{
}

Rational Rational::Add(const Rational& r1) const
{
    int numerat = num * r1.getDenominator() +
                 denom * r1.getNumerator();
    int denomin = denom * r1.getDenominator();

    return Rational(numerat, denomin);
} 

void Rational::Print()
{
    cout << num << "/" << denom <<endl;
}
```

When debugging the code, the Add function returns the values 13 & 5 as expected and the correct constructor does as well. Unfortunately, the Print() function retains the original fraction instead of the new values.

Comment: By now you will have read the answers and realized you were **misled** by (1) bad naming (an imperative "command" name for a pure function) and (2) bad call pattern design (member function instead of free-standing `operator+`). Practical solution: define a freestanding function called `operator+`. Make it a `friend` of `Rational`, or alternatively let it use a modifying member function `operator+=`. Generally it's a good idea to name a pure function as a *description of the function result*. For example, `sum`, if you don't want to use `operator+`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the method `Rational Rational::Add(const Rational& r1) const`, as the signature suggests and how it is implemented doesn't modify the object on which it is called but rather create a new `Rational` instance and returns it.

Try with:

```
myRational.Print(); //Displays 3/5 as expected
myRational = myRational.Add(2);
myRational.Print(); //Displays 3/5 instead of 13/5
```

**An hint**: the fact that the signature has `const` at the end means that the method doesn't modify anything of the instance on which it is called which means that such method could never modify the `myRational` on which you call it.

Answer (score 1):

This function :

```
Rational Rational::Add(const Rational& r1) const
```

returns the result to the calling scope. You are not storing the result anywhere. Hence, you are getting the `myRational` original values.

Try saving the value in an object and then printing. If you want to keep the original content of `myRational` as well, then try this :

```
int main()
{
       Rational myRational(3,5);
       myRational.Print(); //Displays 3/5 as expected
       Rational myRational2 = myRational.Add(2); //Result stored in new object
       myRational2.Print(); //Printed new object values
       return 0;
}
```